# Как получить значение произвольного поля acf в javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api

Есть сайт на **wordpress** с установленным [плагином произвольных полей](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)
Есть поле `the_description`, значение которого хочу получить и обработать в скрипте. для чего воспользовался [JavaScript API плагина](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/javascript-api/)

в созданном мною файле **custom.js**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var foo1 = acf.get('the_description');
console.log(foo1);
});
```

Предварительно подключив в **functions.php** скрипты

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method(){
wp_register_script( 'acf-input', acf_get_dir( "assets/js/acf-input.min.js" ), array('jquery'), acf_get_setting('version'), true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery','acf-input'),null,true);
});
```

Но, в консоли получаю *null*, хотя ошибок нет

```
acf.add_action('ready', function( $el ){
  var foo2 = acf.get('the_description_natural');
  console.log(foo2);
});
```

При такой записи тоже *null*. Что делаю не верно и как получить значение произвольного поля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышел на самое правильное решение, которое заключается с создании локализованных переменных через [localization API in PHP](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Решение такое: в **functions.php** создается локальная переменная, в содержимое которой помещается значение произвольного поля `get_field` и которая привязывается к скрипту в котором будет выводится.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery','acf-input'),null,true);
wp_localize_script('custom', 'custom_vars', array(
    'natural' => get_field("the_description_natural")
    )
);
```

А далее уже в самом скрипте `custom.js` ее выводим:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log(custom_vars.natural);
});
```

Решение почерпнул [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239827/adding-advanced-custom-field-to-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по документации, надо делать так:

```
acf.getField('the_description'); // не acf.get()
```

И я сомневаюсь, что есть функция акция `ready` у acf. В любом случае, существует `acf.addAction`, но не `acf.add_action`.

Comment: спасибо, но получаю пока не понятно что - объект в таком виде `Object { cid: "acf25", data: {}, "$el": {…} }`

"И я сомневаюсь, что есть функция акция ready у acf. "
на самом деле есть: и ready, и load - я брал здесь https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-custom-javascript-fields/

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю так:

```js
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $foo1 = $('#description').val();
  console.log(foo1);
 });
</script>
```

```html
<input id="description" type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_field('the_description'); ?>">
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но самое верное и оптимальное решение я привел ниже